# How to add to array then output items?

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I have a bunch of users with a description for each, and I want to add these descriptions into an array. Then I want to read the array, split each description, and set the results as variables. Example descriptions would be:

`italian, mexican` or `french, american`

This is what I am currently doing:

```
<?php
    $stack = array();
    $blogusers = get_users( 'orderby=nicename&role=author' );
    foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
        array_push($stack, $user->user_description );
    }
    $out = array_map('trim', explode(',', $stack));
?>
```

Then I do

```
<ul>
    <li><?php echo $out[0]; ?></li> 
    <li><?php echo $out[1]; ?></li> 
    <li><?php echo $out[2]; ?></li> 
    <li><?php echo $out[3]; ?></li> 
</ul>
```

But I get a list with no results values

- 
- 

**UPDATE**

Tried

```
$stack = array();
$blogusers = get_users( 'orderby=nicename&role=author' );
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
    $users = array_map('trim', explode(',', $user->user_description) );
    array_push($stack, $users);
}
```

Then

```
<li><?php echo $stack[0]; ?></li> 
<li><?php echo $stack[1]; ?></li> 
<li><?php echo $stack[2]; ?></li>
```

Comment: Why do you explode $stack? I think you need to explode user_description.

Comment: because i want to trim and explode each word within the description as they are italian, american,...

Comment: @jh1711 tried  $stack = array();
 $blogusers = get_users( 'orderby=nicename&role=author' );
 foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
  $users = array_map('trim', explode(',', $user->user_description) );
  array_push($users, $stack);
 } then echo $stack[0];

Comment: wrong order for array_push see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just explode each description and then push each of the elements returned by the explode onto the array. This is assuming you don't care about duplication.

```
$stack = array();
$blogusers = get_users( 'orderby=nicename&role=author' );
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
    $descTokens = explode(',', $user->user_description);
    $stack = array_merge($stack, $descTokens);
}

<li><?php echo $stack[0]; ?></li> 
<li><?php echo $stack[1]; ?></li> 
<li><?php echo $stack[2]; ?></li>
```

Comment: You could just use `array_merge()` instead of a loop.

Comment: nope it is actually good that i have repeated value in the array as i am doing all of this in order to create stats. Actually is there a way we could get the total number of the same values? like `2` italian ?

Comment: @miken32 You're right, updated the answer. This is cleaner. I was under the impression that `array_merge` would dedup, but that it is looking like that is only the case with key values. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at `$stack` after your loop is finished, you'll have something equivalent to this:

```
<?php
$stack = [
    "italian, mexican",
    "french, american",
    "canadian, irish",
];
```

If you run this through explode, you're not going to get anything because you're passing it an array. In fact, if you had proper error reporting set up, you'd get warnings about passing an array instead of a string. I think what you want to do is this:

```
<?php
    $blogusers = get_users( 'orderby=nicename&role=author' );
    foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
        $out[] = $user->user_description;
    }
?>
<li><?=$out[0]?></li> 
<li><?=$out[1]?></li> 
<li><?=$out[2]?></li>
...
```

If you actually need this in separate variables, you can `explode()` it, but you can't output an array to the page:

```
<?php
    $blogusers = get_users( 'orderby=nicename&role=author' );
    foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
        $out[] = explode(",", $user->user_description);
    }
?>
<li><?=$out[0][0]?></li> 
<li><?=$out[0][1]?></li> 
<li><?=$out[1][0]?></li>
<li><?=$out[1][1]?></li>
...
```

Comment: that's fine but then i won't have each description as a separate output, as stated in the quetsion each description is "italian, american" and so on. I need to split each of these words and be able to list them as a separate list

Comment: excellent thanks a lot, this works but accepted the other answer as it is closer to what i was doing and simpler to handle it